# How to use KTorrent?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, bittorrent, ktorrent

Can anybody tell me how to use KTorrent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can add torrent directly by double clicking on that torrent file or add it manually by clicking on add torrent file. leave other option as default

Answer (score 4):

Having that *****.torrent file in desktop.Open your ktorrent,click File>>Open, browse to your desktop then click open that *****.torrent file you just downloaded through firefox. Observe few seconds while your ktorrent client is greeting the "handshakes" with other peers, then you will notice that download begins.

Answer (score 1):

Download a torrent file and open it with KTorrent (right click → open with).

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KTorrent

http://ktorrent.org/wiki/index.php/Manual

Answer (score 0):

If you want to link the torrents you download from Firefox to ktorrent just click on a torrent and when it says open with search for ktorrent. Should be in /usr/bin/ktorrent. That way everytime you download a torrent it will use ktorrent.

If you want to have access to ktorrent via torrents you already have downloaded. Then.

1. Right click on a torrent file and select Properties.
2. Select OPEN WITH tab
3. Select KTORRENT from the list. If it is not from the list click on ADD and search or type ktorrent.

This way you will make a relationship between all torrent files and ktorrent.